# iPhone 6 device displays app in stretched mode

Tags: iphone, swift, ios-simulator, xcode7, stretched

When doing a test run on an actual iPhone 6 I noticed that things seemed much tighter than on the simulator during development. Cleaned the build, restarted devices and emptied the Derived Data folder and still the same result. Then I thought the screen layout looked exactly like on the iPhone 5 and turns out it was. When I took a screenshot of the iPhone I found this black enclosing rectangle as seen below. On the actual iPhone that black frame was not visible. Instead the gray content area and nav bar were stretched to fill the display.

I have seen similar issues in cases where there is no LaunchScreen. But in those cases A) the scaling occurs on the simulator as well and B) the app's screen is centered vertically. Not the case here.

Pertinent facts: 
- This is Xcode 7.3.1
- The project is universal and using size classes /  auto layout and is in Swift
- Project uses a LaunchScreen
- All xibs are versioned for iOS 9.3 / Xcode 7
- The test iPhone is an iPhone 6 running iOS 9.4

Anybody have a clue of what is going on? TIA!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Solved]
I kinda knew that there was something entirely stupid behind this whole thing - and I was right. After trying different things like removing the LaunchScreen in favor of old-fashioned launch images, reinstalling Xcode, disabling auto-layout I thought the project itself must have been hosed. Started a new one from scratch and still had the same results. From there it was quite simple - all apps on 2 iPhone 6s displayed the same symptoms, so it was the iPhones, not the code. Turns out both being linked to the same account had Display Zoom enabled (Settings:Display and Brightness:View). Don't know when or how, but nobody every noticed. Hope this helps some other poor soul :]